# How do I display a DIV when an anchor is active in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make the following code only display when the url ends in **#404**?

```html
<!--404 code-->
<style>
  .div1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-color: #ff0263;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <font face="century gothic">
    <div class="div1" name="div1">
      <span id='close' style="cursor:pointer" onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>x</span> The vite you were looking for could not be found. <a href="/404-what-to-do"><button class="button button5">What do I do now?</button></a></div>
  </font>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
          .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
      };
    };
  </script>
  <style>
    #close {
      float: right;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 2px 5px;
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
    #close:hover {
      float: right;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 2px 5px;
      background: #ccc;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#id1").click(function() {
        $(".div1").css('display', 'block');
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I run this website called Vite - vite.website (Google: Vite Flash Engine). and if I could set it up so that when it reaches a 404, it will redirect to vite.website/**#404**. How do I make the following code visible only when the anchor, **#404** is active?
Thanks!

Comment: This is not **code**, this is CSS - styling declarations.

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is css.but you can use jquery.
you can get the hash of the current url of the page and use if statement for your aim.

Answer (score -1):

you can get the hash location of a webpage using

```
window.location.hash
```

So, maybe something like this can work (assuming you're using jQuery)

```
function hashIs404() {
var hash = location.hash.slice(-1);
    if (hash === "404") {
        //Display things
        //$(selector).addClass(classname); recommended
    } else {
        //Hash is not 404
        //$(selector).removeClass(classname); recommended
    }
}
```

and call this function `hashIs404();` by binding it to `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = hashIs404;
```

As for actually displaying it, use the if case and

```
$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheet-location.css');
```

Hope I could help if not entirely solving the issue :)

Comment: You don't need jQuery for any of this. Not that I encourage answering this question altogether.